# How to create an Dependent measure in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 reports displaying data as

`Filter Partner Name (Applies only to Report1)`

```
Report 1:                                   
Country Name : XXX
Members Count:1500

Report 2:
Partner name : XYZ
Members Count:1203
```

`On applying filter only to Report 1 : Member count changes
now how can i show the data on Report 2 for the Members Count displayed on Report 1?`

`Report 2 should have members count that is displayed on Report 1 only`

*What i'm looking is like a dynamic Count(ID) in Report 2  that changes every time there is a change in Count(ID) of Report 1
on Applying Filter to Report 1*

[image]

On clicking on bar like above the Data in Report 2 must display only for the (72 members) as Shown Below

How to do this in Tableau 8?

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand, why can't you just apply Partner Name filter to both reports (right click, apply to worksheets,...)?

That way both reports will only display data for the selected partners. You can even build a dashboard with both reports side by side, an put a quick filter so you can select the partners you want to show, and apply the filter to both sheets at the same time.

If this does not work, I'm going to need a little more detail of what you're trying to do, how your database is organized, and how you built the sheets.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks but its not like you said, i need some parameter thing such that when that parameter(Having Countd(ID)) in report1 changes the same COUNTD(ID) reflects in Report2 .

Comment: Step back, do not focus on how (maybe you don't need a parameter) focus on what you're trying to do. Both reports have the same database? What fields and measures (and calculations) are being used in each report. When you change the filter, how report 1 changes, and how you want report 2 to change?

Comment: `The Filter (P NAME) applies to Report 1 only (say like after filter the reports get Countd(ID)=300 for these 300 members,Report2 must reflect when i click on the bar`  The reports got same DB

Comment: You mean like this? http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards

Comment: If not, try to explain as if I didn't know your base nor reports (which I don't). What bar you're clicking, how Report2 should react ('must reflect' is not very clarifying)

Comment: Saw your edit. Action filter in dashboard should do the trick (my last link)